# YouTube buffers faster than vanilla HTML Video element even when using the same source (how I can match it?)

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video

I been able to get the list of sources of a video hosted in YouTube an use them directly in a HTML Video element in my page (you know the url with https://rr#---sn-0opoxu-hutey.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...etc-etc-etc)

But when I play the video in the HTML Video element the buffer is slow (the video pauses a little because every 8-10 seconds is not buffered enough), and if I play the same source in YouTube page it buffers more and faster (in the same computer, same network, same video/source).

Is something that YouTube is doing that I don't? Because YouTube is also using a HTML Video element to display the video. Maybe a script? Because the HTML code of the Video element is not that different than the one I'm using.

Comment: What's the definition of the video element you get? - does it loads equals in your browser if you copy/paste the url on the browser?

Comment: What you mean by "definition"? If I copy/paste the URL the video buffers slowly too.

Comment: my bad, I mean "resolution" of the video - i.e 360p, 480p, etc.

Comment: 720p and 1080p (I tested it in different resolutions) but the issue is that YouTube is doing something to buffer more and faster than the default Video element.

Comment: @pruebaprueba What browser/OS are you testing on? I use Chrome on Windows and usually it plays WebM or AV1. Make sure your HTML tag is also testing same codec as the Youtube video. **(2)** Was your _"list of sources"_ all MP4? (_eg:_ it was from a Youtube downloader site that offered only that option)..

Comment: Chrome and Firefox. Yes, all mp4. Not from youtuber downloader (my own code) but in practice, yes, should be the same source.

Comment: Apparently, the YouTube player uses the sources with video and audio separately, that makes it load faster. Now the problem is how to play the video and audio synchronously, since trying to synchronize it with JS in some browsers (Safari) the lag is big